# Concept of template class in C++20

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm new in advanced usage of templates and concepts, so here is a liitle bit complex problem:

- I have some `Traits` concept of many traits for each of `Source` classes:

  ```
  template<typename _Traits>
  concept Traits = requires
  {
     std::same_as<std::decay_t<decltype(_Traits::token)>, std::string_view>;
  };
  ```
- I have some template class that uses this concept to handle `object_one` with various traits (for example, half of `Source` classes returns `object_one`):

  ```
  template <concepts::Traits _Traits>
  class Object_one_handler final
  {
      static std::string handle_object(const object_one& obj) {/*...*/}
  };
  ```
- Then I have `Objects_handlers` concept of handlers for various objects from set `{object_one, object_two, object_three}` from various `Sources` with their `Traits`:

  ```
  template<template <concepts::Traits _Traits> class _Objects_handlers, typename _Object>
  concept Objects_handlers = requires(const _Object& obj)
  {
     // has handle_object method
     { _Objects_handlers<???????>::handle_object(obj) } -> std::same_as<std::string>;
  };
  ```
- Finally, I creating some `database` with specified as template parameter `Object_handler`:

  ```
  template<concepts::Objects_handlers _handler>
  class database 
  {...};
  ```

(Actually all of concepts have additional requirements, but it doesn't matter here)

---

So **problem** is in last `Objects_handlers` concept:

```
template<template <concepts::Traits _Traits> class _Objects_handlers, typename _Object>
concept Objects_handlers = requires(const _Object& obj)
{
  // has handle_object method
  { _Objects_handlers<???????>::handle_object(obj) } -> std::same_as<std::string>;
                      ^^^^^^^
};
```

I can't check `_Objects_handlers` method without template parameter (obviously) and I can't properly set the template parameter which must be one of `Traits`.

How can I do that?

And actually it may be problem in usage of `Objects_handlers` in template of `database` class, so one more question: how to use it?

---

P.S. It can be XY problem or not about concepts at all... Maybe composition with strategy pattern will be more usefull, but still want try to create this maybe useless, but workable concept.

Comment: Before you can proceed any further, you'll need to rename everything. All tokens that begin with an underscore and an uppercase character are reserved for the use of the C++ library, and should not be used. Who knows what kind of symbol clashes are muddying the entire issue. Finally, after renaming everything, can you reframe your question as a single, self-contained, [mre], and explain either the compilation error, or whatever the technical issue is, in concise terms? High level design questions are usually off-topic fo Stackoverflow, since they are mostly opinion, not facts.

Comment: First of all, your `Traits` are wrong, because the `std::same_as` in the requires clause only checks the *validity* of the expression. `template<typename _Traits>
concept Traits = std::same_as<std::decay_t<decltype(_Traits::token)>, std::string_view>;` is sufficient.

Comment: @康桓瑋 this concept has others requirements, so I can't simplify it like this (maybe...?)

Comment: @PP189akaMgroot. Then use nested requirements:  `requires
{ requires std::same_as<...>; };`

Comment: Don't use identifiers starting with underscore then an uppercase letter. These are reserved for the implementation. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I tried to, but this is already minimal example which you can test by copying three first blocks (I can't post link to some online compiler because they doesn't provide c++20). About issue: I can get various compilation errors, but I don't think that they might help (`Undefined Reference` for example). The problem is in this: `_Objects_handlers<?????>::handle_object(obj)` place: what should I write to check static method of template class with any of `Traits`...

Comment: And well yes, underscore in identifiers is forbidden. This is just an example for better reading, they are not using in actual code

Comment: Using the forbidden identifiers here has already detracted from the discussion twice. How is that "better reading"? A [mre] means you remove **all** irrelevant issues and potential issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's reduce this problem a lot.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct C {
    void f();
};
```

Now, your goal is to write a concept that takes any class template (e.g. `C`) and checks that *every specialization of it* has a nullary member function named `f`.

```cpp
template <template <typename> class Z>
concept HasF = requires (Z<???> z) {
    z.f();
};
```

The problem is - class templates in C++ just don't work like this. Even for a particular class template, like `C`, you can't require that *every* specialization has `f`. There's no way to ensure that like somebody, somewhere, didn't add:

```cpp
template <> struct C<std::vector<std::list<std::deque<int>>>> { };
```

All you can do is check that a *specific* type has a nullary member function named `f`. And that's:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept HasF = requires (T t) { t.f(); };
```

---

The type-constraint syntax, `template <Concept T>`, is only available for concepts that constrain types, not concepts that constrain templates or values.