# Constrain to function objects with one reference parameter of any type

Tags: c++, lambda, constraints, c++-concepts, stdtuple

I'm probably scratching the possibilities of C++ a bit here. I have this tuple for each function that executes a function for every tuple element. Now I want to constrain the incoming function object in a way that only allows for function objects with one reference parameter of *any type*, since the value type of a tuple varies of course. Can this be done?

I tried it with `std::invocable<auto&>` but this doesn't seem to work.

[CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:48,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:48,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:48,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:48,startLineNumber:7),source:%27//+%23pragma+once%0A%0A%23include+%3Cconcepts%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctuple%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E+/*+index_sequence+*/%0A%0Atemplate+%3Cclass+Tuple,+std::invocable%3Cauto%26%3E+F%3E%0Ainline+constexpr+decltype(auto)+for_each_in_tuple(Tuple%26%26+tuple,+F%26%26+f)%0A%7B%0A++++return+%5B%5D+%3Cstd::size_t...+I%3E%0A++++(Tuple%26%26+tuple,+F%26%26+f,+std::index_sequence%3CI...%3E)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++(f(std::get%3CI%3E(tuple)),+...)%3B%0A++++++++return+f%3B%0A++++%7D(std::forward%3CTuple%3E(tuple),+std::forward%3CF%3E(f),%0A++++std::make_index_sequence%3Cstd::tuple_size%3Cstd::remove_reference_t%3CTuple%3E%3E::value%3E%7B%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Os+-pthread%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <concepts>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility> /* index_sequence */

template <class Tuple, std::invocable<auto&> F>
inline constexpr decltype(auto) for_each_in_tuple(Tuple&& tuple, F&& f)
{
    return [] <std::size_t... I>
    (Tuple&& tuple, F&& f, std::index_sequence<I...>)
    {
        (f(std::get<I>(tuple)), ...);
        return f;
    }(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), std::forward<F>(f),
    std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>::value>{});
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I don't see anything wrong with `f(auto&, int = 0)`? What about `f(auto&...)`?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Right it probably doesn't make sense in most cases. But what if it does? How do I go about it?

Comment: `std::invoke` always take reference parameter, not sure what you want.

Comment: You could make sure it is invocable with tuple_element... Or decltype(std::get... Looks like you don't need "for any type" for this

Comment: "for any type" is not directly expressible, however you can make sure it is invocable with a particular type, such as your own detail type... Then it may be invocable with most things (one can delete call operators, e.g.)

Comment: @JeffGarrett Indeed I could check if it's invocable with any of the tuple_elements! That would be an even narrower constraint which is good.

Comment: @JeffGarrett that would be the cleanest solution, but would require you to replicate the `for_each` function as a concept. So basically the concept is "if the for_each function compiles for the given function, then the function satisfies the concept" https://godbolt.org/z/veaY6s5oq

Comment: Another option could be to use function traits that let you query the arity of a function. Then you could use `template <typename F> concept single_argument = (function_traits<F>::arity == 1);`. This will probably not work with default arguments or auto parameters/templated functions https://godbolt.org/z/hT37sW7qj

Comment: Nicely done @joergbrech, unfortunately it would require all of the tuple elements to be convertible to a common type :/

Comment: @YSC? Sorry, I am not following, where would the requirement, that all tuple elements must be convertible to a common type come from?

Comment: @joergbrech [there](https://godbolt.org/z/rdxobeTTf) (I only added an element to your tuple).

Comment: JeffGarrett I like your idea of using a detail type. Here is an option, where you check if the function is invokable on a detail type, that is convertible to anything. It would only disregard implicit conversion https://godbolt.org/z/ebv6cT7d8

Comment: @YSC ok I think I get what you are getting at. When passing the function as an argument, I have to choose a specific overload. So a potential overload of `print` for strings would cause an ambiguity?

Comment: @joergbrech That's it. And as far as I know, C++ doesn't provide a solution (yet).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm probably scratching the possibilities of C++ a bit here

Yes you are.

Currently, C++ only enable us to define a concept constraining a type (with the `template<Concept T>` syntax). You need it to constrain a template (see [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69496604/5470596)) so your function `F` does not restrict all elements from `Tuple` to share a common type or be convertible to it.

There exist proposals to define such a feature, but none accepted yet; e.g. [P1985 "Universal Template Parameters
"](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1985r3.pdf).